# FindNext returns file names even when used with faDirectory only

Tags: delphi, file, find, delphi-xe

I am trying to list all the directories in a given directory. I have this code:

```
var
    srec: TSearchRec;

begin
    // folder is some absolute path of a folder
    if FindFirst(folder + PathDelim + '*', faDirectory, srec) = 0 then
        try
            repeat
                if (srec.Name <> '.') and (srec.Name <> '..') then
                    ShowMessage(srec.Name);
            until FindNext(srec) <> 0;
        finally
            FindClose(srec);
        end;
```

But for some reason I get messages about file names instead of directories only. I thought that using `faDirectory` would make `FindFirst` and family only return names of directories. What am I doing wrong? If I change it to

```
if FindFirst(folder, faDirectory, srec) = 0 then
```

Then it only shows the name of `folder` but not as an absolute path (relative to `folder + '/..'`) and quits afterwards.

I realise that I can check if it is a directory by making sure that `(srec.Attr and faDirectory) = faDirectory` but I feel like that's doing things in a roundabout way and there should be a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using delphi xe,  check the [`TDirectory.GetDirectories`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetDirectories) function.

The [`SysUtils.FindFirst`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FindFirst) Documentation has the answer to your issue.

```
function FindFirst(const Path: string; Attr: Integer; var F: TSearchRec): Integer;
```

> The Attr parameter specifies the special files to include **in addition
>   to all normal files**. Choose from these file attribute constants when
>   specifying the Attr parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this. But any idea what was wrong with my first attempt?

Comment: As such, you need to check for the presense of the `faDirectory` flag in the `srec.Attr` field before using `srec.Name`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
var
  Dir: string;
begin
  for Dir in TDirectory.GetDirectories('c:\') do
    ShowMessage(Dir);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You has to use the filter to remove files
some small changes to your code

your code:
`folder + PathDelim + '*'`
change to

```
folder + PathDelim + '*.'
```